# « Peux-tu […] ? » est-il trop familier pour être employé dans une conversation ?

Tags: oral, questions

Je voudrais vous demander si l'expression « Peux-tu […] ? » appartient à la langue trop courante dans la conversation quotidienne ?  Si je rends visite à mon amie en France, je demande « Peux-tu me passer la carte qui est posée sur la table, s’il te plaît ? », je peux dire ça ?  Ou autrement, je peux dire « Est-ce vous pouvez me passer […] ? ».  Quelle est l’expression la plus familière ?

N.B.: Si je dine en ville avec mon patron, quel est le meilleur moyen de demander les choses simples — le sel, par exemple ?

(Maybe I am thinking too much in what is the best way to ask questions with the elders or bosses — do the French care so much ? How to sound more natural ?)

Comment: a good trick to know if you're supposed to use tu or vous in France (in Québec it would be different) is to ask yourself if you'd use "could you" or "can you" if you were asking something to this person. Could-->vous can-->tu It works nearly all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Si je rends visite à la grand-mère de mon amie en France, je demande « Peux-tu me passer la carte qui est posée sur la table, s’il te plaît ? », je peux dire ça? Ou autrement, je peux dire « Est-ce vous pouvez me passer […] ? ». Quelle est l’expression la plus familière ?

Tout dépend du niveau de politesse à employer. Je pense qu'au premier contact, il vaut mieux vouvoyer. "Peux-tu" deviendrait alors "Pouvez-vous". L'utilisation du "vous" est une forme de politesse. Le pire qui puisse arriver, c'est qu'on te demande de ne pas vouvoyer, alors là le "Peux-tu" est tout à fait acceptable, oui.

C'est une question de politesse qui varie beaucoup d'une personne à l'autre, à mon sens.

> N.B.: Si je dine en ville avec mon patron, quel est le meilleur moyen de demander les choses simples — le sel, par exemple ?

"Could you please pass me the salt?" Would translate to "Pouvez-vous me passer le sel s'il-vous-plait?" which is the proper polite way to ask. If you're familiar with the person, you'd maybe use "Pass me the salt" or "Can you pass me the salt?". The former is more of an order "Passe-moi le sel" and the latter would be a less polite way to ask, or a more familiar one "Peux-tu me passer le sel?". It really depends, again, if you're familiar or not with the person.

To be safe, I'd use "vous" until I'm told otherwise or feel we are familiar enough for less formalities.

Answer (score 3):

Pour répondre à la première question, « peux-tu » est une manière totalement acceptable de poser une question dans presque tous les cas. « Est-ce que tu peux » est tout aussi acceptable, mais de niveau peut-être légèrement plus élevé.

Pour ce qui est de la façon de s'adresser à des amis et à des aînés ou patrons, la plus grande différence est l'utilisation du tutoiement ou du vouvoiement. Avec des personnes que l'on connaît bien, on utilise le tutoiement. On pourra alors utiliser « peux-tu me passer le sel » ou « est-ce que tu peux me passer le sel ». En s'adressant à un aîné ou à un patron, il est mieux d'utiliser le vouvoiement, à moins que la personne demande d'être tutoyée. On dira alors  « pouvez-vous me passer le sel » ou « est-ce que vous pouvez me passer le sel ». Pour être plus poli, on ajoutera un « s'il-vous-plaît » à la fin. Le vouvoiement est également de mise lorsque l'on parle à des étrangers.

---

To answer the first question, "*peux-tu*" is a completely acceptable way to ask a question in almost all cases. "*Est-ce que tu peux*" is as acceptable, though perhaps of a slightly higher level.

As for address friends vs elders and bosses, the main difference will be in using different pronouns, namely *tu* vs *vous*, that marks either familiarity or respect. With people you know, friends and family, you use *tu*, so you would say "*peux-tu me passer le sel*" or "*est-ce que tu peux me passer le sel*". When you're talking to an elder or a boss, you'll want to show respect and use *vous*, unless you are asked to use *tu*. Therefore you'd say "*pouvez-vous me passer le sel*" or "*est-ce que vous pouvez me passer le sel*". To be even more polite, you'll add a "*s'il-vous-plaît*" at the end. Using *vous* is also appropriate when talking to strangers.

Comment: Pour être plus poli, j'ajouterais surtout un conditionnel.